# Sending map in postman post request

Tags: java, json, dictionary, post, postman

I can't find a good answer as to how to format a map in my json post when I want it to map directly to my Java pojo with the @RequestBody annotation.  I'm assuming the json would look something like:

```
{
    "myInt":"10",
    "myMap":"{1:\"A\"}"
}
```

My pojo would have a `myInt` field and a `myMap` field.  The `myMap` field is of type `Map<Integer,String>`

What does the json for the map look like to get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your JSON structure `myMap` is a `String`. However, even if you remove the quotes from the value of `myMap` you will find that `{1:"A"}` is not valid JSON, valid JSON syntax requires that all property keys are strings. A valid JSON structure would look like `{"1":"A"}`. The deserializer should be able to coerce the key into an `Integer`, so `Map<Integer, String>` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure to have something like the following resource method:

```
@Path("/url")
public class Test {

    @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response post(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, when you send the request through POSTMAN, select the type as POST, then select the "raw" option and then just send a JSON in the "body" with the values you want to put in your Map. Remember to select "application/json" . Jackson will transform the JSON into a Map for you.

```
{
   "myInt": 10,
   "myMap": {
         1: "A"
     }
}
```

Comment: this is missing quotes around the 1 and 10 to make it valid json

Comment: @Artanis you do not need quotes around the value, numeric values are valid JSON syntax, only the key must be a string. A value can be any of the primitive types (object, array, string, number, boolean).

Comment: oh okay so it's just missing quotes around the 1